# Can't find this element on page even though it is exist C# selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I have tried finding this element for the longest time and I can't figure it out. My goal is too set the value to a number using setattribute but I can't find the element.

```
<input type="tel" id="cvNumber" tabindex="1" data-shortname="cvv" class="cc-input ncss-input pt2-sm pr4-sm pb2-sm pl4-sm u-align-center" "cvv"="" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" value="" maxlength="4">
```

Here is some code I used to try to find the element

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@class='cc-input ncss-input pt2-sm pr4-sm pb2-sm pl4-sm u-align-center');
driver.FindElement(By.Id("cvNumber");
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='cvNumber'");
driver.FindElement(By.className("cc-input ncss-input pt2-sm pr4-sm pb2-sm pl4-sm u-align-center");
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='tel'");
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: All the lines are invalid: note that there is no closing parenthesis for `FindElement()` and no closing square brackets in XPath expressions

Comment: when you tried with driver.FindElement(By.Id("cvNumber"); , what does it return ?

Comment: Forget that they are invalid that is not the point I can't located the element because of some issue with the html so I need to find another way

Comment: Is the element visible on the page source? (Right click the webpage and view page source)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is anything wrong with the element selector. Its likely that you are not waiting for the element long enough

```
 var wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
 var myElement = wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.Id("cvNumber")));
 if(myElement.Displayed) {
   //do stuff
 }
```

Or its possible that the element is inside a frame, so you need to switch to the frame before executing code above.

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.id("frameId")));
```

Comment: I had to switch to the right frame, this worked thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

try with this code :

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='cvNumber'][@type='tel']");
```

Comment: still getting the same error that it is unable to locate the element

Comment: Can you check for iframe ?

Answer (score 0):

As per your shared HTML, you can use below location strategies

Xpath

```
.//*[@id='cvNumber']
```

CSS selector

```
#cvNumber
```